# How to encrypt SQLite DB using SQLiteCrypt

Tags: android

I wanted to ecrypt the db file that i am storing on the sdcard. I have looked into SqliteCrypt library for serving my purpose but its using C libraries to perform the encryption/decryption.

I would like to know if anyone has successfully included the library in their project? If yes, please guide me through the process.  Any guidance or any samples will be of great help.

Edit :  Anyway, it's much more simpler to implement encryption yourself based on plain Java. It's not difficult – @barmaley

I want to encrypt the whole db file as single unit. Not individual data fields. Please let me know if there is any alnerate mechanism to achieve this.

Comment: I think it's useless, unless you're going to buy sources and compile them against Android NDK. Anyway, it's much more simpler to implement encryption yourself based on plain Java. It's not difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [SQLCipher for Android](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher).

Answer (score 0):

try to use [SqlcryptSDK](https://github.com/lendylongli/android-sqlite-encrypt)

it is my project, i use android source code and add encrypt method in it.finally build the sdk  and demo;